# Asynchronous task

Tags: android

I have created an asynchronous task like this:

```
private class LongOperationcheckall extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result="Start";
        try
        {
            Looper.myLooper().prepare();
            // Looper.loop();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int k=0;k<13;k++)
            {
                checkall();
                this.publishProgress("Show the dialog");

                //count++;
            }

            result="Success";
            checkallcomp++;

            OnscanComplete();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            checkallcomp++;
            OnscanComplete();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i("Progress", "Progressincheck");
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String params ) {
        Log.w("all Check",params);

        // Execution of result of Long time consuming operation
    }
}
```

I have added code,

```
Looper.myLooper().prepare();
```

to call to this task as

```
taskAllcheck = new LongOperationcheckall();
taskAllcheck.execute();
```

The fourth time when I click on start button the fourth time, it gives the exception

> Can't create handler inside the thread inside thread which not called looper.prepare

Only, when I run in the device it executes OK in the emulator, but after add this line, the error comes as only one looper may be created per thread when I click on the start button for the fourth time and call `taskAllcheck.execute();`.

Comment: What does checkall() method do? "Can't create handler..." exception usually occurs when you're trying to do something that's only allowed to do in the UI thread, in a background thread.

Comment: checkall() only check the setting like bluetooth on or off,gps on or off in device and update the status according to it in database

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Perhaps, these are operations that must be executed on the UI thread. You can put them into a Runnable in the activity.runOnUIThread() method, this way you'll overcome the Looper exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please think of the asynchronous thread as a UI thread that has a inbuilt handler to update your UI. No matter what, it is a thread. So now that is cleared, I don't see where you have actually written the `checkall()` function. The check all function needs to be a local methodology for the asynchronous task to call in the background. It cannot be a method in your main class. If that is the case, there is no point of having a asynchronous task. So please add the `checkall()` function to your asynchronous task.

Next, there is no need of the looper in the asynchronous task. The handling of the data is taken care of by:

> this.publishProgress("Show the dialog");

Please make sure that you pass in anything that you want. Either an `int`, `string`, `boolean`, `array` or anything and everything can be handled in this. So make wise use of the implementation.

Now, make the inside the `onProgressUpdate()` correspondingly and hence also please check that if you want something from the UI thread to be executed, such as a methods or something. That can be done in this method.

Now make the changes I have told you. Please get back to me and I will be in a better position to work with you. If we can pinpoint the problem. Take care.